# droid user interface implemenation

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like to write an application that would run initially on a Motorola Droid.  The application would retrieve row(s) from a database and display some textual data from the rows as well as an image associated with the record that will be stored on the SD card.

I really think that the results would be best displayed in a fashion similar to the Calendar app that ships with the Droid - that is the data  and associated image will scrollable left and right by dragging the  current "page".

I assume that some of you will know how this is implemented - I dont' seem to be able to ask the right question when searching.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git;a=tree) the Calendar app you are referring to?  Looking through the source might help.

Comment: Thanks!

The source looks like it might be what I am after; I will run it in an emulator to check.

It will probably be this evening, as I have a virtual server to upgrade and I must babysit that for now.

And thanks to nasufara (I assume) for adding the android tag.  For whatever reason, I had trouble with the tags... I don't know if it was naivete, Firefox or something else.